# how to process message received in kafka using spring integration transformer

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

i am posting below data into kafka and receive through spring integration channels and transform into **Log** object, how do i transform below data into Log object using spring integration transformer? appreciate any help here

> 'Log(clientKey=string, payload=string)'

Here is the channel adapter code

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
    KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter = new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(
            kafkaListenerContainer());
    kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setPayloadType(Log.class);
    kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel());
    return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
}
```

when i try to convert within the service activator using below

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Log msg = objectMapper.readValue(arg0.getPayload().toString() , Log.class);
```

its failing with

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Log': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `'Log(clientKey=string, payload=string)'` doesn't look like well-formed JSON as you would like to convert from later in the Spring Integration.

Another concern that your do `kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setPayloadType(Log.class);`. This way you don't need any downstream transformation and `MessagingMessageConverter` in the `IntegrationRecordMessageListener` will do the conversion job for us.

However we still need to have a proper data to be able to convert from.

You also need to keep in mind that Apache Kafka has its own mechanisms to deserialize a `byte[]` from the wire. See Spring for Apache Kafka for more information about conversion and (de)serialization: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes

For the proper JSON conversion Spring Integration provides a `JsonToObjectTransformer` component, which can be used with the `@Transformer` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#_common_transformers

**UPDATE**

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "processChannel")
@Bean
public JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
   return new JsonToObjectTransformer(Log.class);
}
```

Comment: i am able to serialize the value i am pushing to kafka as JSON and here is the output  '{"clientKey":"string","payload":"string"}', now how do i use JsonToObjectTransformer using Java,

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Can I use same JsonToObjectTransformer  with List<Sometype> I must implement GenericTransformer?

Comment: Please, raise a me SO thread with much more info.

Comment: Stack Oveflow question (or thread): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask